# Convert comparison operator string representations to actual operators in java

Tags: java, compare, comparison

Basically, I have some comparators as an enum:

```
public enum Comparator {
  EQ("="),
  GTE(">="),
  GT(">"),
  LT("<"),
  LTE("<=");
}
```

And what I want to be able to do is to actually compare two variables (doubles) using the values of these enums.
Something like `private boolean conditionPassed(double var1, double var2, Comparator comp) {...}`.

Is there a way of interpreting these strings as actual comparison operators? Or is there a way of defining the enum differently to accomplish this?

Comment: [`Comporator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is an existing Java interface. Do yourself a favor and rename your `enum`.  You can use `switch` within your method to implement actual comparisons. When you implement equality keep in mind that you need to use `==` (not `=`).

Comment: Don't use switch.  Make one field in the enum a `BiFunction<Double, Double, Boolean>`.

Comment: Why?  What's your use case?  What's wrong with normal primitive comparing?  Especially since those operators work for all numeric types.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using lambas and a [BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html)

```
public enum Comparator {

    EQ("=", (d1, d2) -> d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()),
    GTE(">=", (d1, d2) -> d1 >= d2);
    // ... other entries ...

    private final String operator;
    private final BiPredicate<Double, Double> evaluation;

    Comparator(String operator, BiPredicate<Double, Double> evaluation) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.evaluation = evaluation;
    }

    public boolean evaluate(double var1, double var2) {
        return evaluation.test(var1, var2);
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why pass a String operator to the constructor.  Wouldn't it just be called `Comparator.EQ.evaluate(a,b)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public enum Comparator {
    EQ("=", x -> x == 0),
    GTE(">=", x -> x >= 0),
    GT(">", x -> x > 0),
    LT("<", x -> x < 0),
    LTE("<=", x -> x <= 0),
    NE("!=", x -> x != 0);

    public final String display;
    public final IntPredicate predicate;

    private Comparator(String display, IntPredicate predicate) {
        this.display = display;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    
    public boolean test(double left, double right) {
        return predicate.test(Double.compare(left, right));
    }
}

private boolean conditionPassed(double var1, double var2, Comparator comp) {
    return comp.test(var1, var2);
}
```

And

```
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.EQ));   // true
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.GTE));  // true
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.GT));   // false
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.LT));   // false
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.LTE));  // true
System.out.println(conditionPassed(0, 0, Comparator.NE));   // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this certainly isn't very sexy, but it supports both primitive values and objects that implement the comparable interface.  Depending on the use case, it my not solve your problem.  But this is how I might approach it.

```
double a = 111209.000;
double b = 111209.000;
System.out.println(EQ(a,b));
System.out.println(GE(20,10));
System.out.println(!GE(20,10));
System.out.println(LE(100000.f, 200000.f));
System.out.println(!GE('A','B'));
System.out.println(!GE("B","A"));

System.out.println(evaluate(20,30, ContainingClass::LE));               

public static <T> boolean evaluate(T a, T b, BiPredicate<T,T> pred) {
    return pred.test(a,b);
}
```

prints

```
true
true
false
true
true
false
true
```

The  methods

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean EQ(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) == 0;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean GE(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) >= 0;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean GT(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) > 0;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean LE(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) <= 0;
}
...
...
...
```